# GNU make compiling with date offset

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu

I have a main machine running Linux with the current time;

I have also a virtual machine running Windows 7 with a different time;
the offset is in the past, so when I generate source code, the files have a date which is older than the real date.

I'm building the sources using GNU make on the main machine.

When I build the first time, it's building without any problem;
when I modify some files in the virtual machine, they will have a date which is older than the executable, so running "make" does not capture those as changes and doesn't compile the modified source files again.

Is there a way of solving my problem?

(Maybe running a script at the end of the compilation to set the same offset in the executable OR telling make to keep an hash of the sources?)

EDIT:
As a temporary solution I'm using an external BASH script invoked by the Makefile:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Makefile: @./Compile.sh "$(CC)" "$(SWITCHES)" "$(OBJECT)" "$(SOURCEFILE)"
#                          $1      $2            $3          $4

# TODO:
#  P1 This approach does not consider .h files changing. 
#     "g++ -dD -fpreprocessed -E $SOURCEFILE" and whitespace/newline removal before comparison.
#     diff -uwB $(g++ -dD -fpreprocessed -E $SOURCEFILE) $(g++ -dD -fpreprocessed -E $SOURCEFILE.previous)
#     Checksum on all output object not to link again.

SOURCEFILE="$4"

CHECKSUM=$(cksum < "$SOURCEFILE")

CHECKSUMDIFFERENT=true
echo $@
# If an hash is present already, we compare them.
if [ -f "${SOURCEFILE}.checksum" ]; then
    OLDCHECKSUM=$(<"${SOURCEFILE}.checksum")

    # If the old hash is the same as the new one, the output is up-to-date.
    if [ "$OLDCHECKSUM" == "$CHECKSUM" ]; then
        CHECKSUMDIFFERENT=false

    fi

fi

if [ $CHECKSUMDIFFERENT == true ]; then
    echo "Comparison for \"$SOURCEFILE\" failed, (re)compiling."

    $1 $2 -o "$3" "$SOURCEFILE"

    # Saving the new hash if the compilation has success.
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -n "$CHECKSUM" > "$SOURCEFILE.checksum"

    fi

fi
```

I've also found this http://blog.jgc.org/2006/04/rebuilding-when-hash-has-changed-not.html
But don't know how to apply it to my Makefile.

Comment: Use source control to share the files.

Comment: Fix the time in your virtual machine so it's the same as your host operating system.  Make operates solely by comparing modification timestamps and there's no other alternative algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, I never thought of setting the right date on the machine...

Answer (score 1):

You can run `touch` on your Linux before a build, and set the *correct* date for all source files, using `find` to filter the ones that changed after given time (see `-cnewer`).